# Компьютер видит видеокарту но не использует ее?

Tags: видеокарта

После очередного включения ПК возник шум кулера, сначала я подумал это кулер проца но потом понял что видеокарта не используется компьютером а вся нагрузка идет на проц, скидываю скрин. Видеокарта вроде работает но заходя в игры они стали тормозить. Что делать ребята есть мысли?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Драйвера последние стоят? Монитор подключен к порту на карте?

Comment: Все разобрался я не туда кабель воткнул, спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2):

Все правильно - у Вас стоит интегрированная карта в материнскую плату и внешняя NVIDIA - можно определить через правую клавишу мыши, какая карта будет использоваться как  конкретных программах, так и в целом в системе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]